# HTAccess Open only to Website

Tags: .htaccess

To secure my site I placed blank htmls along with an htaccess file in every subdirectory but I didn't realize the denying all access would also mean denying access from the website itself. When I try to load a page, and it goes into the Images folder, the server responds with:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

So how do I change this htaccess code:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all

Options All -Indexes
```

To deny access to everything *outside* of the website, meaning the website itself can access its own content (images, js, css) but no one outside can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already accomplished your stated goal, but obviously that's not *really* what you're after. Basically *everybody* that browses to your site is coming from outside and requesting assets from your server. When I request `index.html`, or any other page from your server, it doesn't send me a complete package as it were, with all of the page's assets wrapped up inside, it just sends me the text that comprises `index.html`. At that point the browser parses that and handles it accordingy; when it comes across an image tag that has a `src` on your server, it fires off a new request for that asset, and hopefully your server sends it back in response. [Yes, I realize that was all ridiculously simplified.]

As you've got things set up now, you're denying access to anybody and everybody that requests any assets from your server, which is why you're getting the `403` responses. So whatever it is you actually want to do is going to require a more tightly focused approach. I'll take a stab at it and guess that what you really want to do is prevent people from hot-linking your images?

Comment: well I just don't want people to access the subdirectories. Yah I can just put a blank html but I want to secure it a little more than that.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want them to be able to see a listing of the contents of the subdirectories, or do you want them not to be able to access anything in them at all?

Comment: i don't want them to be able to see ANYTHING, in fact it would be best if I can display the Forbidden message

Comment: Um, well then you're already all set, you've completely blocked http access to your directories and their contents.